# AutoMapper failed to convert List<Model> (1 item) to List<DTO> (0 item) with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below the code I use to fill a table in Index.cshtml. Property list has 1 row and after the map model has 0 rows. Am I missing something? I was expecting that property model would have 1 row too.

```
// GET://
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //get
        List<Company.Model> list = repo.ReadAll();
        //to map
        List<Company.DTO> model;

        //config for mapping
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<Company.Model>, List<Company.DTO>>());
        //create mappper
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        //the map
        model = mapper.Map<List<Company.DTO>>(list);

        //return
        return View(model);
    }
```

Please let me know when I am something doing wrong! My first Automap and first post on Stack Overflow. Thanks!!

Comment: Not an answer, but shouldn't mapping configs be done in another file?

Comment: I normally map the individual items rather than the entire list.  You can do it either way but something like `var dtoList = modelList.Select(l => Mapper.Map<Company.DTO>(l)).ToList();`  That said, I think your problem is you don't have the mapping itself defined.

Comment: Can you show us what the individual models look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map one model to another.  Automapper is intelligent enough to map collections:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Company.Model, Company.DTO>());
```

Right now, you haven't told it how to map a `Model` to a `DTO`!  It only knows how to map a `List<Model>` to a `List<DTO>`, which is great, but it doesn't know how to map *each individual element in the collection*!

Now it knows how to map the model the dto, it *also* knows how to map a collection of one to a collection of another:

```
model = mapper.Map<List<Company.DTO>>(list);
```

It doesn't matter what each collection type is, as long as they're both collections.  The input can be an array and you can map it to a `List<DTO>`, no problem.  Like I said, Automapper is intelligent when it comes to collections.  It just needs to know how to map *your* stuff.

This means you shouldn't ever need to map a collection of things to a collection of widgets.  Just map things to widgets, and let Automapper do the rest.  It's a hard worker  :)

Comment: This actually worked and not this  result.Select(customer => _mapper.Map<CustomerViewModal>(result)).ToList();